# Java Heap Size for Zend Studio, soft limit reached, Robust hardware

Tags: java, zend-studio, heap-size

I have a computer with Intel I7 2600 3.4Ghz processor, 32GB RAM, Windows 7 professional x64, JVM updated.

In Zend Studio when run Source -> Format Code over many files, Zend crash with warning: Java Heap Size.

I read about setting values in ZendStudio.ini, my relevant settings:
-Xms1089M
-Xmx1089M
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

But I can't increment these limit.

Any alternative for fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you increment? 32 bit JVM?

UPDATE: Did some research. While it is possible to edit Zend Studio's JVM usage,

[This support forum post](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=57483&ei=1qEPUMnXJsjRiAKKh4GIAg&usg=AFQjCNHUbjGoW5mDND0azhOms8c7le95Zw) states 32 bit JVM is needed (I guess they use 32 bit native DLLS.

A 32 bit JVM is limited to about 1.5 GB addressable space. You might be able to tweak things further, but it's gonna be a stretch.

Therefore your only solutions are mostly out of your hands

- Zend Studio updates to 64 bit support
- Zend Studio adjusts memory usage
- You figure out a way not to use as much memory yourself.

Comment: Zend Studio in 64 bits is not in my hands.

Comment: I did adjust the memory variables (as mentioned, in ZendStudio.ini) to highest possible (if higher it not open)

Comment: As I stated, with excrutiating pain you can make it allocate more. Do a google for 32 bit windows jvm 2gb limit and I'm sure you can get a bit more. Otherwise, you have the options I specified.